# For how long will xamarin ios performfetch run?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

For how long will xamarin ios performfetch run?
I'm running a for loop to test for how long will the performfetch run and it only runs like for 15 seconds. is there an official timelimit for it?

here is my code

```
 public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{


                for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "i", i));
                }
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**30 seconds**

Refer to the **Discussion** section of the Apple docs for `performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the needed data. If you do not call the completion handler in time, your app is terminated. More importantly, the system uses the elapsed time to calculate power usage and data costs for your app’s background downloads. If your app takes a long time to call the completion handler, it may be given fewer future opportunities to fetch data in the future.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application?language=occ

Comment: Ok, so I have 30 seconds even if I wrap my code in  BeginBackgroundTask and EndBackgroundTask?

Comment: @JoseManuelOjeda yes, a `PerformFetch` is supposed to be fast, grab some new data and invoke the completionHandler, if you can not call the completionHandler in <30secs, you should re-architect your data requirements within the fetch. Remember if you are not calling the completionHandler, the OS will reduce/eliminate its calls to your prefetch, but 30 secs is a long time on terms of a https/get and the faster you call the completion the more the OS will call the fetch (assuming the user loads your app often),  it is all about battery life..., i.e. my fetches are designed to last <10 secs